# How to install autotrace in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, software-installation

Ubuntu 16.04 [had a package](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/autotrace.1.html) for [autotrace](https://github.com/autotrace/autotrace), but 18.04 does not seem to have any.

What is the easiest way to install autotrace on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sadly I haven't found a ppa or replacement for this on Bionic (18.04) and Cosmic (18.10), but I just now compiled from source without issues (on both) as follows:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install intltool imagemagick libmagickcore-dev pstoedit libpstoedit-dev

git clone https://github.com/autotrace/autotrace.git
cd autotrace
#unnecessary command for clarification should bugs be introduced later
git rev-parse HEAD
#6468859336870a663106d8179578867caf2cfced

./autogen.sh
#put everything into /usr/{bin,lib,share,include}
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib ./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install
```

PSTOEDIT SUPPORT IS WORKING. Ming (swf support) is the only thing disabled as the libming-dev package is also unavailable. No need to link anything.

```
which autotrace
/usr/bin/autotrace

autotrace -v
AutoTrace version 0.40.0.

uname -rvm
4.18.0-15-lowlatency #16-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Thu Feb 7 12:28:15 UTC 2019 x86_64

lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.10
Release:    18.10
Codename:   cosmic
```

You can safely uninstall (should a .deb become available) by redoing the exact same install process once again and add:

```
sudo make uninstall
```

If this isn't working for you I'm guessing it's a missing .deb on your system. Comment with your issue and ill update the apt syntax accordingly.

Comment: the command `make` returns `make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.` on `Ubuntu 20.04`. Am I missing anything?

Comment: I haven't notziced that I running the commands inside an active conda environment. My bad, the `make` did not return any error when called in global.   Nonetheless, I had to follow the indication provided by @NicolaRaul below to make `autotrace` work.

Comment: @ivanp the commands work with the correct git revision. I'll update when I have a good ppa package created with most releases supported. I've actually been keeping this up to date for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rather boring solution.
Any better solution is warmly welcome! :-)

Compile from source code, excluding `pstoedit` because otherwise [compilation fails](https://github.com/autotrace/autotrace/issues/21):

```
sudo apt install intltool imagemagick libmagickcore-dev pstoedit
git clone git@github.com:autotrace/autotrace.git
cd autotrace
./autogen.sh
./configure --without-pstoedit
make
sudo make install
```

Running it fails miserably:

```
autotrace: error while loading shared libraries: libautotrace.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But this works:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib autotrace -v
AutoTrace version 0.40.0.
```

In order to make other software (such as Inkscape) find it, I had to do the following:

```
cd /usr/lib
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libautotrace.a libautotrace.a
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libautotrace.la libautotrace.la
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libautotrace.so libautotrace.so
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libautotrace.so.3 libautotrace.so.3
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libautotrace.so.3.0.0 libautotrace.so.3.0.0
```